# Loop the sound alert from a Local Notification [Swift 3.0 - Xcode 8]

Tags: swift, loops, audio, uilocalnotification

Ive got Local Notifications working. However Im having trouble trying to loop the notification sound. Ive been looking through other questions on the topic, however I cannot seem to get a code to work without error.
Im trying to loop the sound for the maximum 30 seconds allowed. The sound file is 1 sec long, so I want to loop it 29-30 times. 
Please help!

Heres the code:

from the notification:

```
Content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "Note.m4a")
```

How do I loop this 30 times?

Comment: To fix this, I just looped the audio file. However, it still only plays for 1 second when the local notification comes up. Then I get this error `skipping input stream` ?? Can anyone help?